# Programmatically assign new letter to existing drive with C++

Tags: c++, c, windows, disk, drive-letter

I want to change a drive letter. For example, I can use [diskpart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diskpart) to assign a new letter to a drive (a USB disk or a new hard disk).

How can I implement it in C/C++?

Comment: I came across [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364014.aspx) on msdn. Maybe it helps someone (it was exactly what I was looking for).

Comment: Check the following links:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364014%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
(This one is an example with source code, very useful for what you want to do) And the reference to "DefineDosDevice" function:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

[`SetVolumeMountPoint(L"X:\", volumeName.c_str())`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365561.aspx)

Comment: From the docs "...  a directory on another volume (for example, Y:\MountX). The string must end with a trailing backslash ('\')." -- thats a great *bad* example.

Comment: Yeah, luckily that example is irrelevant in this case.

Answer (score 1):

A trivial and easy way to do this would be to just shell out to `diskpart`:

```
int main () {
  int i = system("diskpart ..."); // Add args here.
  cout << "command exited with code: " << i;
  // ...
}
```

It has an `/s` parameter that you can use to supply a script to run inside `diskpart`, so you can simply write a text file out with the relevant subcommands and pass that into `diskpart` with your `system(...)` call.

Comment: thanks, that is my last choice if i can't implement it with c++ code